# Cronjob with Cron.php

Tags: magento-1.7, php, configuration, cron

in my Magento Store I need to set some Cron to:
- Run maintenance.php
- Apply Catalog Rule and after that Refresh Cache
- Refresh Sitemaps

My hosting create a curl to cron.php but I don't know how to modify my cron.php to run this operations.
Can someone help me?
This is my cron.php

> require 'app/Mage.php';
>
> if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
>       echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
>       exit; }
>
> // Only for urls // Don't remove this $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] =
>   str_replace(basename(**FILE**), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
>   $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(**FILE**),
>   'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
>
> Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
>
> umask(0);
>
> try {
>       Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
>       Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
>       Mage::dispatchEvent('default'); } catch (Exception $e) {
>       Mage::printException($e); }

How should I modify it?
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your hosting provider has enabled the default Magento cron. This is good news as now Magento will have the cron running on an interval. In order to add a process that you want to the cron you need to create a new module. Within your config.xml add the following:

```
<config>
...
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <namespace_module>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0,15,30,45 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>module/cron::doSomeAction</model>
            </run>
        </namespace_module>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
...
</config>
```

If you then create a new file with model/cron.php with the following contents:

```
<?php
class MyVendor_Module_Model_Cron
{
   public function doSomeAction()
   {
       // Do your logic here
   }
}
```

Magento will then pick this up when cron runs based on the cron schedule and process the action we created.

Alternatively you could create a new shell command and add this to your linux cron tab.